# Automate user account creation and logon in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, testing, command-line, automation

I have a repetitive testing task I need to do, which I'm hoping to automate. Unfortunately, part of the testing procedure involves creating a new Windows user account, then logging in as the new account to continue testing. I'm fairly sure I can create the new account, but I can't find a way to automate changing user and continuing execution of a bat script. I've found the `tsdiscon` and `tscon` commands for quickly switching user, but as I understand it, `tscon` only works if the account being switched to is already logged in, which doesn't help when the account is brand new.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331947/resume-batch-script-after-computer-restart) question regarding resuming bat file execution after a reboot, which is going to be very useful, but multi-user automation seems to be a much harder problem.

Comment: At this point, you should probably look into learning PowerShell... :-)

Comment: I'm primarily using C#. I got around the problem of automating switching user by using RDP to `localhost` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `net user` command to create a new local user account and then use the `runas` command to execute a program, batch script, or command with the permissions of the newly created user.

If you want to open a desktop session for the new user, you could change the `DefaultUserName` and `AutoAdminLogon` registry key values and then initiate a reboot. The following SuperUser topic might be useful to you:  [Automatic logon](https://superuser.com/questions/28647/how-do-i-enable-automatic-logon-in-windows-7-when-im-on-a-domain)