# Resume powershell script after reboot

Tags: powershell

I have a lot of articles about this subject but none of it is understandable.

My request is very simple. I have two part of my codes ; First of all Code 1 should be work and windows should be restarted. After reboot completion, Code 2 should be work. This process should be done silently at background. Powershell version is 4.0 ( Win 2012 R2 )

**CODE 1 - This code is changing Computer Primary DNS Suffix.**

```
$computerName = $env:computername

$DNSSuffix = "abc.com"

$oldDNSSuffix = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\" -Name "NV Domain")."NV Domain"

#Update primary DNS Suffix for FQDN
Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\" -Name Domain -Value $DNSSuffix
Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\" -Name "NV Domain" -Value $DNSSuffix

#Update DNS Suffix Search List - Win8/2012 and above - if needed
#Set-DnsClientGlobalSetting -SuffixSearchList $oldDNSSuffix,$DNSSuffix

#Update AD's SPN records for machine if part of an AD domain
if ((gwmi win32_computersystem).partofdomain -eq $true) {
     $searchAD = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
     $searchAD.filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(cn=$($computerName)))"
     $searchADItem = $searchAD.FindAll() | select -first 1
     $adObj= [ADSI] $searchADItem.Path
     $oldadObjSPN = $searchADItem.Properties.serviceprincipalname
     $adObj.Put('serviceprincipalname',($oldadObjSPN -replace $oldDNSSuffix, $DNSSuffix))
     $oldadObjDNS = $searchADItem.Properties.dnsHostName
     $adObj.Put('dnsHostName',($oldadObjDNS -replace $oldDNSSuffix, $DNSSuffix))
     $adObj.setinfo()
     #$adObj.Get('serviceprincipalname')
     #$adObj.Get('dnsHostName')
}
```

**CODE 2 - Installing Terminal Services on this computer**

```
Import-Module RemoteDesktop
Add-WindowsFeature -Name RDS-RD-Server  -IncludeAllSubFeature
Add-WindowsFeature -Name RDS-Licensing  -IncludeAllSubFeature
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve this yourself?

Comment: [This is probably relevant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_workflows?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: This seems like a perfect use case for [Desired State Configuration](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-desired-state-configuration-the-basics/).

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to roll your own with log files to check where it left off, you can look into powershell workflows which allows recovery after reboot. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574130(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

powershell commands are very complicated, i decided to do this with batch file.

[Resume batch script after computer restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331947/resume-batch-script-after-computer-restart)